# OData service authentication with SAP Gateway service OpenUI5

Tags: odata, sapui5, netweaver

i have a service url as below

```
http://<hostName>:2020/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZTEST_SRV$metadata
```

When i call this from Chrome browser i ask for username and password if i give username and password, it will show the XML with all the entity sets in that service URL

but in code if i create the instance

```
var model = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("http://<hostName>:2020/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZTEST_SRV/",true,'username','password');
```

its shows the 401 Error

how can i solve this?

My app is not deployed in ABAP repo, or Fiori, this is deployed in other Host on Tomcat

Comment: You need a token that you can get from a SAP service on the SAP portal - I think there is a service that can be enabled whereby you supply user name and password. I would then try passing that in as part of the header. Can't remember the details but am willing to dig if you are still stuck.

Comment: Yes I don't have solution.. Please can you help me

Comment: ask your basis person for the URL for the ping service - should be of the following order: http://********:8000/sap/bc/ping?sap-client=<nnn>

Comment: yes got this service.. this is asking username and password and in response just server reached.. but not the token :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can solve this is 2 ways

1: We can use [SimpleProxyServlet](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/2d/3f5fb63a2f4090942375df80abc39f/content.htm)

2 Establish a [Reverse Proxy](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/06/29/solving-same-origin-policy-issue-in-different-ways) with Apache HTTP Server

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the correct order of the parameters; you may try to supply them as a Map instead, i.e.

```
var model = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel("http://<hostName>:2020/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZTEST_SRV/", { 
    json     : true,
    user     : "<username>",
    password : "<password>"
});
```

Also, compare both requests (the working basic authentication as well as the request from the ODataModel instantiation code)

Does your service support OData V2?

Comment: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Comment: and also i tried with sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel

Comment: The 'preflight' indicates it may be some sort of CORS issue; your service must allow the same-access origin header, see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server, or you can try and reset the headers from the calling service (which effectively overrides the OPTIONS request)